# Haskell print function name

Tags: haskell

Hello i would like to print the names of functions in a list. Is it somehow possible to do so?

my example:

```
import Text.Show.Functions
f1 x = if x == 1 then 1 else 0
f2 x = if x == 2 then 1 else 0
f3 x = if x == 1 then 2 else 0
fs = [f1,f2,f3]
fs
```

writes out `[<function>,<function>,<function>]` but I want `[f1,f2,f3]`

Comment: Functions don't have names *per se*; you can *bind* one or more names to a single function, but the function itself has no notion of which names are bound to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible. If you want named functions, you will have to whip them up yourself; e.g.

```
data Named a = Named { name :: String, val :: a }
instance Show (Named a) where show = name
fs = [Named "f1" f1, Named "f2" f2, Named "f3" f3]
```

Comment: It might go without saying, but now `fs` has a type like `[Named (a -> b)]`, not `[(a -> b)]`. Subsequent code using `fs` would need to adapt.